# Extracting data from Json in Php

Tags: php, json

I have this Json Object Below, I want to extract this data and output it in PHP

```
{"seat_booked":"A5","0":"A5","1":"A3"}
```

then get them into this format

```
$seat_booked = "'A5', 'A5', 'A3'";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode)?

Comment: now there are so many answer updated now, accept the best answer now for future..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are looking for this, its very simple example by using `json_decode()`:

```
$string = '{"seat_booked":"A5","0":"A5","1":"A3"}';
$decoded = json_decode($string,true);
$resuiredString = '"'."'".implode("','", $decoded)."'".'"';

echo $resuiredString;
```

**Result:**

```
"'A5','A5','A3'"
```

**Side Note:**

I suggest you to learn about variable concatenation.

[PHP Concatenation](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php2p5.html)

Comment: Thank you Devpro, This really help me

Comment: @kikuyu1: mention not, if its working for u than dont forget to mark as accepted by click on the left green tick, it will help to others in future..

Answer (score 0):

To get an object from a json in php you can use `json_decode` has explained [here](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php).

But you have another problem, your json is wrong!
If you want to represent a single dimensional array you should at least do this

```
["A5","A5","A3"]
```

Finally, using json_decode:

```
$obj = json_decode('["A5","A5","A3"]');
var_dump($obj);
```

Also, you could do something like:

```
{"0":"A5","1":"A5","2":"A3"}
$obj = json_decode('{"0":"A5","1":"A3", "2": "A5"}', true);
var_dump($obj);
```

**Edit:**

It's not very clear from your question if you are trying to get back an object from a json or if you just want to get a string from it.

If what you need is an string then you don't even need json, you could do this by string manipulation and/or using regex.

But just for completeness, if a quoted comma separated string is what you need you can do this:

```
$array = json_decode('["A5","A5","A3"]');
$str = implode("','",$array);
$str = "'" . $str . "'";
var_dump($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
$json = '{"seat_booked":"A5","0":"A5","1":"A3"}';

$decoded = array_map(
    function($val) { 
        return "'". $val."'";
    }, 
    array_values(json_decode($json, true))
);
```